# Python and Node js communication

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, numpy

I have been trying to communicate between Node JS and Python following this tutorial: http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2015/08/21/python-nodejs-comm/

The python file reads a javascript array and prints the sum using the numpy module. Here is the code for both the python and node js file.

Python code:

```
    import sys, json, numpy as np

    #Read data from stdin
    def read_in():
      lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
      return json.loads(lines[0])

    def main():
      #get our data as an array from read_in()
      lines = read_in()

      #create a numpy array
      np_lines = np.array(lines)

      #use numpys sum method to find sum of all elements in the array
      lines_sum = np.sum(np_lines)

      #return the sum to the output stream
      print lines_sum

    #start process
    if __name__ == '__main__':
         main()
```

Node js code:

```
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
      py =spawn('python', ['compute_input.py']),
      data = [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
      dataString='';

    py.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      dataString += data.toString();
    });

    py.stdout.on('end', function() {
      console.log('Sum = ', dataString);
    });

    py.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    py.stdin.end();
```

Error message:

```
    Error: write EPIPE
      at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
      at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:711:26)
      at Socket._write (net.js:730:8)
      at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:331:12)
      at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:317:5)
      at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:243:11)
      at Socket.write (net.js:657:40)          
      at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
```

Comment: (1) This is not valid Python code. (2) How do you run the scripts?

Comment: (1) Can you clarify what is not valid? (2) I am running the scripts with the node js command prompt.

Comment: The function definitions like `**def read_in():**` should not contain these stars. If you run the Python script separately the interpreter would tell you. I guess node swallows the error message from the child process.

Comment: I understand that python functions do not use **. I wanted it to be clear where the functions were. Please see revised format.

Comment: It's clearer without them :) Have you tried running the Python script manually? There may be less obvious errors.

Comment: How are you invoking the node script and which version of node?

Comment: @kazemakase When I run the python script manually(using IDLE), it keeps running and there is no output. I have to kill the terminal for the program to stop.

Comment: @Malice I am using node 6.11.1. When i type "node pythonexample.js" i get the error above.

Comment: can you make sure u are using python 2 when you invoke the command within node.. python exits prematurely and writing to its stdin or reading from its stdout causes EPIPE error

Comment: You might want to try printibg stderr of py

Comment: Thanks @Malice, using python 2.7 worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python script is throwing an error. The `python` command invoked python3 instead of python 2.7, for which the script was written and the script errored out. `EPIPE` error is thrown because the python script ended prematurely and node tries to read-from/write-to to an already closed pipe.